# Image not showing in react-native in a physical device

Tags: react-native, expo

I am a beginner in React Native. I started learning it today. I was trying to display an image on the screen but I am having some problems here.

my Code

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Image source={{ uri: 'https://i.imgur.com/G1iFNKI.jpg' }} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

when I go to this URL in the browser it shows the image, but no success in the device.

The same image when I download and use it locally, then it works

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Image source={require('./assets/myViewScene.jpg')} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add dimensions to the image and it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to provide `Dimensions` to the `remote` images in order to show them. As mentioned in the docs [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images#network-images), **Unlike with static resources, you will need to manually specify the dimensions of your image for remote images.**

For Example -

```js
<Image source={{ uri: Some_Remote_Image_URI }} />
// This will not load and the image would not be shown.
```

```js
<Image source={{ uri: Some_Remote_Image_URI }} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
// This will load perfectly and the image will be shown.
```

```js
<Image source={require("./path_to_local_image")} />
// This will load perfectly and the image will be shown even if you don't provide the Dimensions.
```

[Working Example Here](https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/image-examples)

Answer (score 1):

For people coming from Google: if your image is an SVG, check `SvgUri` component from `react-native-svg`:

```
<SvgUri
  width="50"
  height="50"
  uri="https://images.com/your.svg"
/>
```

Comment: Excellent point, it was the case for me!